# Is there any FUNCTIONAL difference between this double-padlock analogy and public-private key encryption+signing?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature

Consider the following real-world setup (not hugely practical but in theory it can be done)

There are two types of padlock:

**Regular padlock**:

- anyone can lock it, but only the key holder can open it
- the padlock is public, the key is private

**Combination code padlock**:

- only the owner can lock it, with the correct code
- the padlock is public, the combination code is private

All padlocks, either regular or combination, are engraved with the name of the owner, and this cannot be tampered with or forged onto a new lock. So anyone seeing any padlock knows who it belongs to.

All padlocks can be replicated and distributed to anyone, they are available to the "public"
All keys and combination codes are private, and should be kept secret by the owner of the padlock.

---

You can use these two padlocks together in an interesting way:

Alice wants to send Bob a secret message. And Alice also wants to prove to Bob that she sent the message.

First Alice puts her message in a box and locks it with Bob's regular padlock. Now only Bob can open the box so the message is secret for Bob only.

But anyone could have done that as no key is required to lock a regular padlock. Carol could have sent Bob a message and locked the box with Bob's padlock as all padlocks are publically available.

So secondly Alice needs to prove that she locked the box. She does this by locking her combination padlock ***onto Bob's regular padlock.*** (not onto the box itself, otherwise Bob won't be able to open it)

Alice sends the box to Bob.

---

Bob receives the box. Bob sees that Alice's combination padlock is locked.  Since Alice is the only person with the combination code,  only she could have locked it.

Bob also sees that it's been locked onto his regular padlock, which only he can open. And Bob can now open the box as he has the key to the regular padlock.

Could someone have intercepted the box and swapped the locks? The key to the regular padlock is only known to Bob, and the key to the combination padlock is only known to Alice. So no-one could have opened and replaced the locks.

---

It's not an analogy of how public-private keys actually work on the internet, but in terms of functionality (the benefits received by all parties) I think this is equivalent to sending an encrypted and signed message over the internet. Please correct me if wrong!

I'm interested in a physical analogy of the *functionality* of public-private key pairs, rather than the actual implementation on the internet, for which a great explanation is already provided here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80839/as-an-analogy-to-asymmetric-key-encryption-does-the-following-work-if-not-why

Admin/ mod: please do not transfer this question to crypto exchange, where it might be locked and the key lost forever! Thanks!

Comment: Your analogy is wrong. Eve doesn't need to know the combination to Alice's combination padlock to lock it onto Bob's regular padlock.

Comment: Off-topic is off-topic, and the question belongs on the crypto site.

Comment: I should clarify i mean mechanical combination padlocks, the type that cannot be locked unless you know the code. They stay stuck open until the correct code is set.

Comment: This is to help communicate technical functions to non-technical clients, I think it's useful to bridge the two. The crypto site is too technical for this topic, but if anyone has a suggestion for an alternative site that would be helpful thanks.

Comment: "Eve doesn't need to know the combination to Alice's combination padlock to lock it onto Bob's regular padlock" I'm confused how is that possible?

Comment: Because Bob's regular padlock is open at first. To put two locks together, only one needs to be open.

Comment: Ok, i forgot to say Alice's padlocks are only ever public in the open position. So no-one can close them except Alice. Does that help?

Comment: No, because once Bob unlocks his padlock, then he'll have one of Alice's in the closed position.

Comment: Ok thanks, so that is a flaw if extending the analogy beyond the first transaction. I wonder if there's a physical analogy to fix that.

Comment: Maybe if Bob's padlock has a second permanently-closed ring on it, Alice can loop her combination lock through both rings, so Bob cannot decouple it from her lock. The locks would then have to go back to Alice to be decoupled. A bit convoluted but maybe that works.

Comment: If we assume that padlocks exist that can be copied trivially, then surely we can also assume that stamps exist that cannot be copied. Alice just has to put her stamp on the message; no need for two kinds of locks. In any case, this isn't a programming question. *Maybe* it's on-topic on https://security.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we could just stick with the analogy of a real world signature (or stamp)
But now the padlock example has got me wondering if such a real world equivalent is actually used. Clearly not at scale but maybe there are some interesting historic cases. This could add interest to help convey the concepts.